# Values not getting appended to list while using the multiple processes package on Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm working on a web scraping script and to improve its efficiency, am trying to learn how to use the multiprocessing package in python.

I'm trying to append a set of values to a list and looping over it for several values to get a list of lists.

Here is my current code, but the "temp" list is empty after I run it and I can't figure out why

```
temp= []

def square(number):
    global temp
    x = number * number
    print(x)
    temp.append([number,x])



numbers = [1,2,3,4]

processes = []


for number in numbers:
    process = Process(target=square, args=(number,))
    processes.append(process)


    process.start()

for proc in processes:
    proc.join()


print (temp)
```

In other words, I want my list to contain the values I am appending to it in the function, and I can't figure out why it isn't doing so/ how to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`Process` is not a good candidate for what you are trying to do. You can do this much better with a `Pool`. This way you will avoid accessing that global variable from within different processes.

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool


def square(num):
    x = num * num
    return [num, x]


numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]

pool = Pool()
results = pool.map(square, numbers)

print(results)
```

The output is:
`[[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16]]`